# Using xpath to return array of elements from SOAP response

Tags: php, xml, soap, xpath, simplexml

Given this fragment of a larger SOAP response:

```
<Calendar>
    <CalendarDay Date="2013-10-01" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/">
        <Occupancy>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="2BS" totalRooms="26" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="26" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="3BS" totalRooms="4" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="4" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="BSV" totalRooms="3" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="3" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="CHV" totalRooms="1" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="1" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="D3B" totalRooms="6" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="6" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="DLDB" totalRooms="86" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="86" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="DLDC" totalRooms="81" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="81" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="DLKB" totalRooms="123" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="123" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="DLKC" totalRooms="117" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="117" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="GDDB" totalRooms="4" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="4" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="GDDC" totalRooms="17" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="17" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="GDKB" totalRooms="20" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="20" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
            <RoomTypeInventory roomTypeCode="GMS" totalRooms="3" overBookingLimit="0" soldDeductible="0" soldNonDeductible="0" totalAvailableRooms="3" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/"/>
        </Occupancy>
    </CalendarDay>
    <CalendarDay Date="2013-10-02" xmlns="http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/">
    ...
    </CalendarDay>
</Calendar>
```

I need the `Date` attribute of each `CalendarDay`, then an array of `RoomTypeInventory` elements for each day. All namespaces from the soap Envelope have been registered.

Here's the gist of my code ('a' is a previously registered default namespace):

```
$CalendarDays = $responseXML->xpath('//a:CalendarDay');

foreach($CalendarDays as $CalendarDay){
    $CalendarDate = ($CalendarDay->attributes()->Date);
    echo $CalendarDate . "&nbsp;";
    $CalendarDay->registerXPathNamespace('x', 'http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/');
    $RoomTypeInventory = $CalendarDay->xpath('//x:RoomTypeInventory');
}


$responseXML = simplexml_load_file('FetchAvailablePackages60Days.resp.xml');
```

I registered the namespace 'x' because it was the default namespace declared with CalendarDay.

`$CalendarDay->attributes()->Date` has the correct value. But `$RoomTypeInventory` is empty. 
I've also tried

```
   $RoomTypeInventory = $CalendarDay->xpath('x:Occupancy/x:RoomTypeInventory');
```

which also fails. But

```
   $Occupancy = $CalendarDay->xpath('x:Occupancy');
```

returns an appropriate value, so I assume the namespacing is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you register namespace `a` ?

Comment: All of the various namespaces are registered earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that you're registering the wrong namespace. You're registering `x` as `http://...../Availability/` when the `RoomTypeInventory` elements have the namespace `http://...../HotelCommon`:

```
$aNamespace = 'http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/Availability/';
$hNamespace = 'http://webservices.micros.com/og/4.3/HotelCommon/';

$CalendarDays = $responseXML->xpath('//a:CalendarDay');

foreach($CalendarDays as $CalendarDay){
    $CalendarDate = ($CalendarDay->attributes()->Date);
    echo $CalendarDate . "&nbsp;";
    $CalendarDay->registerXPathNamespace('h', $hNamespace);
    $RoomTypeInventory = $CalendarDay->xpath('//h:RoomTypeInventory');
}
```

Incidentally, if you want to get the Rooms for just the current CalendarDay, you need to use a relative XPath:

```
    $RoomTypeInventory = $CalendarDay->xpath('.//h:RoomTypeInventory');
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't think there'd be a default namespace set on each element. And I didn't look for it out there. Thanks, that did it.